# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object in unity 3D trying to make a function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
 using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
[RequireComponent(typeof(flipPlayer))]
public class enemyInstantiate : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject[] enemies;
    public Transform enemyPos;
    public GameObject enemyClone;



    void Start()
    {

        enemyPos = GameObject.Find("enemySpawn").transform;
        enemyClone = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        enemySpawn();
        flip();
    }

    public void enemySpawn()
    {

        int enemyIndex = Random.Range(0, enemies.Length);
        Instantiate(enemies[enemyIndex], transform.position, transform.rotation);


    }
    void flip()
    {

        enemyClone.GetComponent<flipPlayer>().enabled = true;

    }

}
```

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   enemyInstantiate.flip () (at Assets/Scripts/enemyInstantiate.cs:32)
>   enemyInstantiate.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/enemyInstantiate.cs:18)

i'm pretty new to Unity 3D 
And still having trouble, can you please help out with what the problem is and why am i getting a nullReferenceException.

The error occurs in the line (enemyClone.GetComponent().enabled = true;).

Comment: Which line is the error referencing? Can you update your question with the full error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably in this line

```
enemyClone = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
```

Is returning `null` to var `enemyClone`, and/or in `GetComponent<flipPlayer>()` from line

```
enemyClone.GetComponent<flipPlayer>()
```

also is returning `null`.

When you try to access a member of an object that is the null reference, this error happens.

Therefore, a way to check which reference is null, is debugging via MonoDevelop.

Answer (score 1):

Without the complete error, the only things I can say are:

- Random.Range is a number between min and max INCLUSIVE! So if your length is 4 for example, and you do from 0-4 your range, and you try to access enemies[4] it will break! You need your line to be Random.Range(0, enemies.length - 1);
- Do you have items in your *enemies* array?
- Do you have an enemyspawn in the scene? maybe separate that line into a declaration first, and then make sure the item is not null before trying to access it's transform.

Hope this helps you! If not, please post the line in which the null reference is happening